# Name of a Game of Thrones fan fiction

Tags: story-identification, game-of-thrones, fan-fiction

I am trying to find a fan fiction I read years ago. It is a modern AU *Game of Thrones* fic with the pairing of Jon/Denearys. It involves them having an affair in college while Jon is in a relationship with Ygritte. It is in no chronological order and covers them over many years and including children. The first chapter is Ygritte discovering the affair.

Comment: College? Secret Child of a Former Monarch college?